# How do I force Apache to simply redirect the user and ignore the directory structure?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

Ok, so this problem recently arose and I don't know why it is happening; it's actually two problems in one...

### 0. My .htaccess file, for reference. (EDITED)

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?400
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?401
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?404
ErrorDocument 410 /index.php?410
ErrorDocument 414 /index.php?414
ErrorDocument 500 /global/500.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(.*\.)?(animuson)\.(biz|com|info|me|net|org|us|ws)/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

### 1. My 'pictures' folder is following the hard path instead of the redirect.

I have no idea WHY it is doing this. It's really bugging me. The 'pictures' folder is a symbolic link to another place so that I can easily upload files to that folder without having to search through folders and such via my FTP account, but that's the only thing I use it for. However, when I visit http://example.com/pictures my htaccess sees it as accessing that other folder, which is restricted, and throws a 403 error rather than redirecting to index.php and displaying the page like normal.

I figured it has something to do with that specific folder being a symbolic link causing it to act oddly, but I have determined that my rules are not being applied to folders at all. If I visit folders such as 'css' and 'com' which are folders in the web root, it displays a 404 error page and adds the '/' to the end of the URL because it's treating it as a directory. It also does the same 403 error for my 'images' directory which is set up in the same fashion.

So, the question here is how do I modify my RewriteRule to apply to the directories as well? I want everything accessed via the web to be redirected back to index.php while maintaining the full access path in the address bar, why is it not working? (I'm pretty sure it was working fine before.)

Here's a small chart to show the paths they're following...

```
example.com/pictures  -> pictures/ -> /home/animuson/animuson-pictures -> 403
example.com/com       -> com/      -> 404
example.com/test      -> index.php
example.com/          -> index.php
example.com/images    -> images/   -> /home/animuson/animuson-images   -> 403
example.com/css       -> css/      -> 404
```

**EDIT: Following information added.**
Apache is processing the structure of the directory first. It's determining if the path exists based on what was typed into the address bar. If someone types in a folder name that happens to exist, it will redirect the user to the path with the "/" at the end of the URL signifying that it's a directory. For the 'pictures' directory explained above, the user does not have permission to access that folder so it is redirecting them to a 403 Access Denied page rather than simply showing the page that is *supposed* to be displayed there via the RewriteRule above. My biggest question is why is Apache processing the directory *first* and **how do I make it stop doing that**? I would really love an answer to this question.

### 2. Why is my compression not working? (EDIT: This part is fixed.)

When analyzing my site through a web optimizer, it keeps saying my page isn't using web compression, but I'm almost 100% positive that it was working fine before under the same settings. Can anyone suggest any reasons why it might not be working with this set up or suggest a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of deliberating on Apache's IRC channel, I was finally able to figure out the real reasoning behind this on a fluke. I just happened to be looking at the directory structure using `ls -l` and noticed that all of the symbolic links had somehow has their permissions changed to `animuson:animuson` from the `root:root` original. I tried to run a simple `chown root:root` on them and it had no effect, so I deleted them all and recreated them and the problem has gone away. I don't really have any idea why the permissions made any different in this scenario but the solution worked and everything is okay now. I've also added a `DirectorySlash Off` to my .htaccess file to get rid of the slashes after folders that exist, just to make it look all that much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Where is this .htaccess file situated? At the root or in the pictures directory?

1) You're using `Options -Indexes` which will deny access to directory listings. This is handled by /index.php?403 which in turn will redirect to /403. (I confirmed this by manually going to /index.php?403) I don't see any other rules in the posted .htaccess that are supposed to affect this. So this either happens because either index.php or some other .htaccess file or server rule makes that redirect.

You might also want to check the UNIX file permissions of the directory in question.

2) According to this aptimizer, http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/, compression is indeed enabled for html, js and css files, as specified in the rules. My bet is that the optimizer is being stupid and does one of these three things:

1)) Complaining about images not being compressed. (It's generally a bad idea to compress images because they're typically already compressed and the extra CPU load typically isn't worth it since the net gain is so small. So your rules are OK in this regard.)

2)) It might think that DEFLATE doesn't count as compression, and wants you to use GZip.

3)) It might also react to the externally included StatCounter js file, which is not compressed. (And there's not much you can do about that.)

Comment: As for the 403 redirect, that is being processed by the index file. When it sees an HTTP error in the query string, it redirects to the appropriate error code URL, it is not handled by Apache. The file is located in the root directory for the website. The compression thing is odd because that is the website I am using and it keeps saying "Up to 12008 bytes could have been saved through compression."

Comment: I'll have to think some more about the 403. The compression did work when I tried it before, but no more. Maybe you changed something since then, or perhaps the debug mode does something mysterious?